# Bluetooth connection timed out too soon?

Tags: android, timeout, connection, bluetooth

#### Hey guys!

Got a problem when I connect with a embedded device via bluetooth. 
When I connect with this code:

```
public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception

                mmSocket.connect();
            if(!cancel){
                toMain = threadhandler.obtainMessage();
                toMain.arg1 = 1;
                threadhandler.sendMessage(toMain);
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            if(!cancel){
                Log.e("SecurityExcep", "Oh noes" , e);
                toMain = threadhandler.obtainMessage();
                toMain.arg1 = 2;
                threadhandler.sendMessage(toMain);
                Log.w("MESSAGE", e.getMessage());
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            //Bad connection, let's get the hell outta here
            try {
                Log.e("IOExcep", "Oh noes" , e);
                Log.w("MESSAGE", e.getMessage());
                if(!cancel){
                    mmSocket.close();
                    toMain = threadhandler.obtainMessage();
                    toMain.arg1 = 2;
                    threadhandler.sendMessage(toMain);
                }
                return;
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.e("IOExcep2", "Oh noes" , e);
            }
        }
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("CONNECT_CONSTRUCTOR", "Unable to close the socket", e);
        }
        if(!cancel){
            toMain = threadhandler.obtainMessage();
            toMain.arg1 = 3;
            threadhandler.sendMessage(toMain);
        }
        Looper.loop();
        return;
        // Now it should be paired.. only thing to do now is let the user commit to the rest
    }
```

I search for the device, find it and then connect it via the `mmSocket.connect()`. After that the request is sent to the embedded device in which i enter the `PIN`. After that the request is sent to the phone were I a notification says that a device is trying to pair etc.

Firstly, it shouldn't be a notification! It should be a dialog and I
   guess it's not my fault.

Secondly why do I get the following exception about 20 seconds after I recieve my notification:

```
07-28 11:13:00.537: ERROR/IOExcep(1064): Oh noes
07-28 11:13:00.537: ERROR/IOExcep(1064): java.io.IOException: Connection timed out
07-28 11:13:00.537: ERROR/IOExcep(1064):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connectNative(Native Method)
07-28 11:13:00.537: ERROR/IOExcep(1064):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:204)
07-28 11:13:00.537: ERROR/IOExcep(1064):     at com.se.mainActivity.ConnectThread.run(ConnectThread.java:61)
07-28 11:13:00.537: WARN/MESSAGE(1064): Connection timed out
07-28 11:13:00.537: INFO/MESSAGEHANDLER(1064): Message 2 recieved, on ConnectThread
07-28 11:13:00.567: ERROR/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Adapter:PropertyChanged from /org/bluez/377/hci0
07-28 11:13:00.567: ERROR/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(234): event_filter: Received signal org.bluez.Adapter:DeviceRemoved from /org/bluez/377/hci0
07-28 11:13:00.567: DEBUG/BluetoothService(234): 00:0E:9F:88:A3:C1 bond state 11 -> 10 (9)
07-28 11:13:00.577: VERBOSE/BluetoothEventRedirector(1111): Received android.bluetooth.device.action.BOND_STATE_CHANGED
07-28 11:13:00.577: WARN/CachedBluetoothDeviceManager(1111): showUnbondMessage: Not displaying any message for reason:9
07-28 11:13:00.577: INFO/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(234): agent_event_filter: Received method org.bluez.Agent:Cancel
07-28 11:13:00.627: VERBOSE/BluetoothEventRedirector(1111): Received android.bluetooth.device.action.PAIRING_CANCEL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it's the embedded device that has a 20 sec wait time before it closes the socket and sends a exception thus terminating the pair-process